# Ubuntu 18.10 on Dell Inspiron 13 7000 AMD Ryzen7

Tags: boot, kernel, dell, 18.10

Ubuntu 18.10 live usb will not boot on my Dell Inspiron 7375 13" 2-in-1 laptop. This is a Ryzen 7 machine with Vega graphics. I have ran and installed openSuse, KaOS, and presently running Fedora 28. The AMDGPU driver works for me on these other distros, but I don't think that's the issue. I miss using Ubuntu, as I am a long time user of Ubuntu and Kubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Update, this is what I see when I try to boot. Just repeats over and over.

watchdog: BUG: soft lockup CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [migration/0:12]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [migration, etc for all 8 cores

**Update!!** I finally figured it out! When booting into the live usb, type "e" to edit the boot parameters. Arrow down to the line that starts with "linux", arrow over to where it says "quiet" and "splash". Remove "quiet", "splash". Then type, "noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll", and voila, she boots right up.
 Thanks to Linuxmint for this solution, aka, compatibility mode. Hope this helps others that may have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. nomodeset did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! \[plymouthd:305\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305) and [Ubuntu 18.04 Won't Boot on Dell Inspiron 7375](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036357/)