# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on Inspiron 13 7375 AMD

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 18.04, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I am trying to install/boot my Inspiron 13 7375 to Ubuntu 18.04,
I have followed every guide i can find, none work.

Using the following boot flags in grub:

```
nosplash pci=noacpi rcu_nocbs=0-7 processor.max_cstate=1
```

I was able to get it to boot to the login screen, but from there it freezes, i cannot get any farther.

I have tried the flags found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036357/ubuntu-18-04-wont-boot-on-dell-inspiron-7375)

and i get the error that the irvs table does not contain ioapic[4] & ioapic[5].
I have tried a custom image with 4.19 kernel, no change.

I have also tried Fedora, CentOS, Ubuntu 16.04, and the 19.04 beta.

anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interesting in this question -
I solved same problem by adding `noacpi noapic nomodeset` to grub command
and setting FastBoot to "Thorough" and Virtualization(maybe that's don't needed) to Disabled in BIOS(1.4.1)

I found that [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/argb8m/linux_any_distro_on_a_ryzen_2700u_dell_inspiron/)

Also, everything working exclude HandleLidSwitch