# Cant dualboot Win10 - NTLDR is missing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu and had some problems dualbooting with Windows. However, I managed to make it working. Unfortunately, my Windows disappeared from the boot menu (and I cant even see it in the BIOS), tho I still have it installed. I tried using boot-repair but there was an error and it did not help. I found this post https://askubuntu.com/a/890562/1015491 which did bring my windows back, but it says "Unknown command NTLDR". Is there a way to repair this or eventually other possibility of bringing my win back without reinstalling?

EDIT: My boot-repair report - https://justpaste.it/2d9m2 -  (activating Separate /boot/efi partition resulted in reinstalling grub, causing again my Ubuntu did not want to boot - I repaired it according to this (https://askubuntu.com/a/1050026/1015491) - but windows was still missing. Windows 10 is installed on sdb3, Ubuntu on sdb5.

Comment: NTLDR is the BIOS based version. Is that what you have installed? Since 2012 Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode since Windows 8 released in 2012. Users can install in BIOS mode, but then must install Ubuntu in BIOS mode. Best to run Summary Report from Boot-Repair and post link above in question.

Comment: @oldfred I added the link to the Boot-Repair report. As far as I know, I have UEFI mode.

Comment: How did you install Windows UEFI or BIOS? It is not showing any boot files, either old BIOS boot partition or Windows boot files in the ESP. You either had a Windows BIOS boot and erased the boot partition and converted drive to gpt. Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR. Drives are now gpt, but no Windows entry in UEFI boot and no Windows boot files in ESP.  you also ran Boot-Repair in BIOS boot mode. You have to be consistent for both Windows & Ubuntu. Always in UEFI mode, or always in BIOS boot mode. Not sure if Windows fixes will resolve it or not, but that is not something we do here.

Comment: Originally it was on other disk (UEFI), I moved it using 3rd party program. But i got you. Just a last question - Will reinstalling WIndows fix this if I install it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it should. Its just both Windows & Ubuntu with new UEFI hardware can install in either UEFI or old BIOS boot mode. And it depends only on how you boot install media. So always boot in UEFI mode. Windows also requires drive to be gpt partitioned for UEFI (or MBR for BIOS). If drive is not partitioned correctly, it will erase it and convert it. So be sure to have good backups. If drive is gpt & you have an ESP - efi system partition you should be ok.